# propostional logic and predicate logic

Tags: logic, artificial-intelligence, predicate, first-order-logic

Given the sentence:
1.Tom has a nice laptop
2. Tom goes to restaurant only when mary goes to restaurant

How will i convert this to both propositional logic and predicate logic. I tried to give it a shot, but I am not sure if it is correct.

```
Propositional
1. P = Tom has a nice laptop
   p
2. p= tom goes to restaurant
   q= mary goes to restaurant 
   q->p

predicate 
1. has_a_laptop(tom)
2. Goes_to_rest(mary) - > goes to rest(tom)
```

is this correct?

Comment: no..its an old sample exam paper. Just wanted to see if I am right

Comment: Probably better suited to Mathematics group than here on SO.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about formal logic with no application to programming.

Comment: It does have application. I am learning prolog

Answer (score 0):

You misunderstood the second sentence: it does not say that Tom goes to the restaurant *whenever* Mary does, it says that Tom *only* goes to the restaurant if Mary does, i.e. Tom *never* goes to the restaurant unless Mary does.

Depending on the way you visualise this, you can write it as `q ∨ ¬p` or as `¬q → ¬p`, which are equivalent.

The same problem applies for your first order representation.

Your representation of the first sentence is OK-ish, but you will be multiplicating predicates if you have to add objects and object properties. You also missed an opportunity of expressing the "nice" quality of the laptop.

You can solve both those problems by using reification, i.e. by associating a variable with the laptop object, as in `laptop(x) ∧ nice(x) ∧ has(tom,x)`.